# 1950's Sci-Fi graphic short story about a farm boy, his ham radio and a tiny rocket ship landing in sauerkraut

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This story was about a farm boy who built a ham radio and found himself communicating with aliens on a space ship heading towards Earth. The townsfolk and army gather for the event with food vendors (maybe carnival stuff as well) and the aliens describe how they have landed in a lake of acid with giant plants/monsters in it and die as they are crushed to death by the giant things.

It ends with the farm boy being arrested as the Army General begins eating a hot dog with sauerkraut and bites down on something hard... it is the tiny space ship that no one had seen. I think it may have been in an issue of Weird Fantasy or Weird Science but I'm not really sure.

It was a rather short graphic novel style. There was no video, only communication over the farm boy's ham radio. The boy talked to the approaching aliens while everyone listened and looked everywhere for the ship about to land. It landed in a vendors tray of sauerkraut and the 'acid' was pitting the ships hull and portals. The giant monsters that were crushing the ship were the General’s teeth.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sounds a lot like *Pictures Don't Lie* by Katherine MacLean. This synopsis from Google books sounds a lot like your plot.

> The aliens were friendly. There was no doubt about that, communication via radio and video made that clear. The decision was made to direct the aliens to a landing spot on Earth. During the landing something goes terrible wrong and the aliens crash land in a swamp and are attacked by hostile creatures. Humanity rushes to find the aliens before it's too late, but will they be in time?

A comic version of this story, adapted from the original, called *Chewed Out!* was printed in Weird Science magazine in their March-April 1952 issue. From the EC Comics Wiki, they have this synopsis.

> Herold Setiker has made contact with aliens who he directs to earth. However they report landing in a murky lake which contain acid are being attacked by giant white monsters. The general arrests Herold but finds the pebble he feels in his mouth is actually the space ship.

You can read the full comic containing your story [here](https://readcomiconline.to/Comic/Weird-Science/Issue-12?id=62953).

Comment: @user14111 I think I posted my answer the same time as you made your comment aha. If the OP confirms that this is the right story then that's a good start, apologies I missed the word "graphic" in the question title.

Comment: That sounds very similar to the story I'm looking for. It was a rather short graphic novel style. there was no video, only communication over the farm boy's ham radio. The boy talked to the approaching aliens while everyone listened and looked everywhere for the ship about to land. It landed in a vendors tray of sauerkraut and the 'acid' was pitting the ships hull and portals. The giant monsters that were crushing the ship was the Generals teeth.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. I'll have to check out 'Pictures Don't Lie' as well!

Comment: @Darrell Windels Happy to help! Enjoy rereading it, "Pictures Don't Lie" does also sound interesting although I know how the story ends now haha!